# req.isAuthenticated not worked

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am working on a nodejs express application, i try to make authentication using passport local strategy with email and password but after successfully login when i checked `req.Authentication()` function it gives me false value, so please help me to correct the code.

in my mvc/controller/user/index.js file when i check in eports.auth method consloe.log(req.user) it shows the values , but after successfully redirect i am not getting that req.user is become null

my application structure is

```
 mvc(main folder)
 -------- db.js
 -------- index.js
 -------- package.json
 ----- conrollers (folder)
       -----user  (folder)
            ----- views (folder)
            ----- index.js (js file) 
 ----- lib (folder where middileware, router and other library file exist)
       --------- boot.js
 ----- models (folder)
       ------user.js
 ----- node-modules
 ----- passport(folder) 
       --------init.js
       --------login.js   
       --------signup.js
 ----- public (folder)
 ----- views (folder)
       --------4o4.ejs 
       --------5xx.ejs
       --------footer.ejs
       --------header.ejs
```

mvc/index.js

```
var express = require('./lib/express');
var logger = require('morgan');
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var monk = require('monk');

var app = module.exports = express();

// settings
var dbConfig = require('./db');

//Connect to db
mongoose.connect(dbConfig.url);
var dbMonk = monk(dbConfig.url);

// set our default template engine to "jade"
// which prevents the need for extensions
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// set views for error and 404 pages
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

// Using the flash middleware provided by connect-flash to store messages in session
// and displaying in templates
/*var flash = require('connect-flash');
app.use(flash());*/
app.use(require('connect-flash')());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.flashMessages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
  //console.log('res.locals.flashMessages : ');
  //console.log(res.locals.flashMessages);
  next();
});

// define a custom res.message() method
// which stores messages in the session
app.response.message = function(msg){
  // reference `req.session` via the `this.req` reference
  var sess = this.req.session;
  // simply add the msg to an array for later
  sess.messages = sess.messages || [];
  sess.messages.push(msg);
  return this;
};

// log
if (!module.parent) app.use(logger('dev'));

// serve static files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// session support
app.use(session({
  resave: false, // don't save session if unmodified
  saveUninitialized: false, // don't create session until something stored
  secret: 'some secret here'
}));

// parse request bodies (req.body)
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// allow overriding methods in query (?_method=put)
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));

// expose the "messages" local variable when views are rendered
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  var msgs = req.session.messages || [];

  // expose "messages" local variable
  res.locals.messages = msgs;
  console.log("res.locals.messages : ");
  console.log(res.locals.messages);
  // expose "hasMessages"
  res.locals.hasMessages = !! msgs.length;
  console.log("res.locals.hasMessages : ");
  console.log(res.locals.hasMessages);
  /* This is equivalent:
   res.locals({
     messages: msgs,
     hasMessages: !! msgs.length
   });
  */

  next();
  // empty or "flush" the messages so they
  // don't build up
  req.session.messages = [];
});

app.use(cookieParser());

//Configure Passport
var passport = require('passport');
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Initialize passport
var initPassport = require('./passport/init');
initPassport(passport);

// Make our db accessible to our router
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    req.db = dbMonk;
    next();
});

// Make our passport accessible to our router
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    req.passport = passport;
    next();
});

// load controllers
require('./lib/boot')(app, { verbose: !module.parent });

app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  // log it
  if (!module.parent) console.error(err.stack);

  // error page
  res.status(500).render('5xx',{title:"500 Error"});
});

// assume 404 since no middleware responded
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.status(404).render('404', { url: req.originalUrl,title:"404 Page Not Found" });
});

/* istanbul ignore next */
if (!module.parent) {
  app.listen(3000);
  console.log('Express started on port 3000');
}
```

lib/boot.js

```
 /**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('../lib/express');
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = function(parent, options){
  var verbose = options.verbose;    
  fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/../controllers').forEach(function(name){
    verbose && console.log('\n   %s:', name);
    var obj = require('./../controllers/' + name);
    var name = obj.name || name;
    var prefix = obj.prefix || '';
    var app = express();
    var handler;
    var method;
    var path;

    // allow specifying the view engine
    if (obj.engine) app.set('view engine', obj.engine);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/../controllers/' + name + '/views');

    // generate routes based
    // on the exported methods
    for (var key in obj) {
      // "reserved" exports
      if (~['name', 'prefix', 'engine', 'before'].indexOf(key)) continue;
      // route exports
      switch (key) {
        case 'login':
          method = 'get',
          path = '/'+name+'/login';
          break;
        case 'logout':
          method = 'get',
          path = '/'+name+'/logout';
          break;
        case 'auth':
          method = 'post',
          path = '/'+name+'/login';
          break;
        case 'add':
          method = 'get',
          path = '/'+name+'/add';
          break;
        case 'save':
          method = 'post',
          path = '/'+name+'/save';
          break;
        case 'show':
          method = 'get';
          path = '/' + name + '/:' + name + '_id';
          //path = '/' + name + '/:id';
          break;
        case 'list':
          method = 'get';
          path = '/' + name + 's';
          break;
        case 'edit':
          method = 'get';
          path = '/' + name + '/:' + name + '_id/edit';
          break;
        case 'update':
          method = 'put';
          path = '/' + name + '/:' + name + '_id';
          break;
        case 'create':
          method = 'post';
          path = '/' + name;
          break;
        case 'index':
          method = 'get';
          path = '/';
          break;
        default:
          /* istanbul ignore next */
          throw new Error('unrecognized route: ' + name + '.' + key);
      }

      // setup
      handler = obj[key];
      path = prefix + path;

      // before middleware support
      app[method](path, obj[key]);
      verbose && console.log('     %s %s -> %s', method.toUpperCase(), path, key);
      /*if (obj.before) {
        //app[method](path, obj.before, handler);
        app[method](path, obj[key]);
        verbose && console.log('     %s %s -> before -> %s', method.toUpperCase(), path, key);
      } else {
        app[method](path, obj[key]);
        verbose && console.log('     %s %s -> %s', method.toUpperCase(), path, key);
      }*/

    }

    // mount the app
    parent.use(app);
  });
};
```

controller/user/index.js

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var bCrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var passport = require('passport');

//check authenticated method
var isAuthenticated = function (req,res,next) {
  // if user is authenticated in the session, call the next() to call the next request handler 
  // Passport adds this method to request object. A middleware is allowed to add properties to
  // request and response objects
  //console.log("req.user : ");console.log(req.session.user);
  //if (req.session.user) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    console.log("Authenticated");
    return next();
  }
  console.log("Not Authenticated");
  //if user is not authenticated then redirect him to the login page
  res.redirect('/user/login');
}

//add one more handler
exports.before = function(req, res, next){
  var id = req.params.user_id;
  //console.log(id);
  if (!id) return next();
  // pretend to query a database...
  process.nextTick(function(){
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('user');
    collection.findOne({"_id":id},{},function(e,docs){
       if(e){
        console.log(e);
       } else {
        req.user = docs;
        console.log(req.user);      
       } 
    });   

    // cant find that user
    if (!req.user) return next('route');
    // found it, move on to the routes
    next();
  });
};

//add user 
exports.add = function(req,res, next){
  res.render('add',{title:"User Registration"});
}
//login user
exports.login = function(req,res,next){
  res.render('login',{title:"User Login"});
}
//logout user
exports.logout = function(req,res,next){
    req.logout();
    //req.session.user = null;
    res.redirect('/user/login');
}
//login post
exports.auth = function(req,res,next){
  /*req.passport.authenticate('login',{
            successRedirect: '/users/',
            failureRedirect: '/user/login',
            failureFlash : true
  })(req, res, next);*/
  passport.authenticate('login', function(err, user, info) {
    //console.log("userrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr");
    //console.log(user);
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/user/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      //console.log("user11111111111111111");
      //console.log(user);
      //console.log(req);
      console.log(req.isAuthenticated());
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      //console.log("ressssssssssssssssssssssssssss");
      //console.log(res);
      //req.session.user = req.user;
      //req.session.passport = req.user._id;
      return  res.redirect('/user/' + user._id);
    });
  })(req, res, next);  
}

//save user data
exports.save = function(req,res,next){
  /*var body = req.body;  
  db.users.push({name:body.user.name,pet:[],id:3});*/

    var db = req.db;     
    var userName = req.body.name;
    var userEmail = req.body.email;    
    var userPhone = req.body.phone;
    var userOldPassword = req.body.oldpassword;
    var userPassword = req.body.password;
    var userID = req.body.id;

    var collection = db.get('user');

    if (userID) {
      //if pwd is changed
      if((userOldPassword) && (userOldPassword != "")) {
          collection.findOne({"_id":userID,"password":createHash(userOldPassword)},{},function(e,docs){
                if(e){
                  console.log(e);        
                } else {
                  //update user with new pwd
                  collection.update({"_id":userID},{"name":userName,"email":userEmail,"phone":userPhone,"password":createHash(userPassword) }, function(err, result) {
                          if (err) {
                              // If it failed, return error
                              res.send("There was a problem updating the information to the database.");
                          } else {
                              res.message('User Updated!'); 
                              // And forward to success page                   
                              res.redirect('/users/');  
                          }
                    });        
                } 
           }); 
      } else {
          //update user without pwd
          collection.update({"_id":userID},{"name":userName,"email":userEmail,"phone":userPhone }, function(err, result) {
                          if (err) {
                              // If it failed, return error
                              res.send("There was a problem updating the information to the database.");
                          }
                          else {
                                res.message('User Updated!'); 
                                // And forward to success page                   
                                res.redirect('/users/');  
                          }
                    });  
      }       
    } else {
      collection.insert({
           "name":userName,
           "email":userEmail,
           "phone":userPhone,
           "password" : userPassword,
           "status" : "inactive",
           "created" : Date.now()
          }, function (err, doc) {
              if (err) {
                   // If it failed, return error
                   res.send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
              } else {
                   res.message('User Added!'); 
                   // If it worked, set the header so the address bar doesn't still say /adduser
                   //res.location("/users/");
                   // And forward to success page                   
                   res.redirect('/users/');                   
              }
        });
    }
}
//show user list
exports.list = function(req, res, next){
  console.log("req in +++++++++++++++++++++++++++=");
  console.log(req.user);
  //check authentication  
  isAuthenticated(req, res, next); 
  var db = req.db;
  var collection = db.get('user');
  collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
      if(e){
       console.log(e);
      } else {
       console.log("user list : "+docs);
       res.render('list', {"users" : docs, title: 'User List'});
      } 
  });
  //res.render('list', { users: db.users, title : "Users List" });
};

exports.edit = function(req, res, next){
   var id = req.params.user_id;
  console.log(req.params.user_id);  
  var db = req.db;
  var collection = db.get('user');
    collection.findOne({"_id":id},{},function(e,docs){
       if(e){
        console.log(e);        
       } else {
        res.render('edit', { user: docs ,  title : "Edit User"});
       } 
  }); 

};

exports.show = function(req, res, next){
  console.log("??????????/??????");
  console.log(req.isAuthenticated());
  console.log(req.params["user_id"]);
  isAuthenticated(req, res, next);
  var id = req.params.user_id;
  console.log(req.params.user_id);  
  var db = req.db;
  var collection = db.get('user');
    collection.findOne({"_id":id},{},function(e,docs){
       if(e){
        console.log(e);        
       } else {
        res.render('show', { user: docs, title : "Show User" });
       } 
  });     
};

exports.update = function(req, res, next){
  var body = req.body;
  req.user.name = body.user.name;
  res.message('Information updated!');
  res.redirect('/user/' + req.user.id);
};

// Generates hash using bCrypt
var createHash = function(password){
    return bCrypt.hashSync(password, bCrypt.genSaltSync(10), null);
}
```

passport/init.js

```
var login = require('./login');
var signup = require('./signup');
var User = require('../models/user');

module.exports = function(passport){

    // Passport needs to be able to serialize and deserialize users to support persistent login sessions
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        console.log('serializing user: ');console.log(user);
        done(null, user._id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
       User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
           console.log('deserializing user:',user);
           done(err, user);
        });
    });

    // Setting up Passport Strategies for Login and SignUp/Registration
    login(passport);
    signup(passport);

}
```

passport/login.js

```
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('../models/user');
var bCrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

module.exports = function(passport){

    passport.use('login', new LocalStrategy({
            usernameField : 'email',
            passwordField : 'password',
            passReqToCallback : true
        },
        function(req, email, password, done) {
            var db = req.db;
            var collection = db.get('user');            
            collection.findOne({ 'email' :  email },
                function(err, user) {
                    // In case of any error, return using the done method                    
                    if (err)
                        return done(err);
                    // Username does not exist, log the error and redirect back                    
                    if (!user){
                        console.log('User Not Found with email '+email);
                        //return done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'User Not found.'));
                        return done(null, false, req.flash('info', 'User Not found.'));                 
                    }
                    console.log('check before valid password');
                    // User exists but wrong password, log the error 
                    if (!isValidPassword(user, password)){
                        console.log('Invalid Password');
                        //return done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'Invalid Password')); // redirect back to login page
                        return done(null, false, req.flash('info', 'Invalid Password')); // redirect back to login page
                    }
                    // User and password both match, return user from done method
                    // which will be treated like success                    
                    return done(null, user);
                }
            );

        })
    );


    var isValidPassword = function(user, password){
        //console.log("Hashed Pwd : "+password);
        return bCrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not to provide **even** more context?

Answer (score -1):

I solve it by myself that deserializeUser is not working properly when i use

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        var collection = db.get('user');
        collection.findOne({ '_id' :  id },function(err, user) {
        //User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
           console.log('deserializing user:',user);
           done(err, user);
        });
    });
```

instead of

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
            User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
               console.log('deserializing user:',user);
               done(err, user);
            });
        });
```

my User.findById function is not worked properly!!!!! :)

Comment: but i get another problem of 
"Error: Can't set headers after they are sent." two time when i go to success page and there is checked for authentication.

Comment: "Can't set two headers after they are sent" implies that you may be rendering a page twice (or more) in the same request